# Can't see a sentence correction

Tags: grammar, modifiers

> **To work as a loan officer, an education in financial planning is required.**

I don't see a grammar mistake in the above sentence, if there is any?

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for posting. Please add a bit about where this was written and who told you it needed correction. I am mystified as well but more context will make for better understanding.

Comment: What might be wrong? It looks okay to me.

Comment: Educations don't work as loan officers.

Comment: It's probably a case of 'passive voice-ism". The person who's complaining probably has the idea that passive voice constructions are grammatically incorrect whereas they are grammatically correct and can be very useful but are often frowned upon by the writers of some style guides.

Comment: 'To work as a loan officer, one requires an education in financial planning' addresses the misplaced modifier issue. Though I thing Pullum would find more fault with the nitpicker here; the original is hardly unclear.

Comment: The sentence looks incorrect according to this GMAT video (2 min: 30 sec) and this question is related to Dangling modifier. : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJytzy-TpR4&list=PLnfGpXq-pbX6aU5zG6ZwehYFFKmU_VJJ5&index=5

Comment: I agree with @TinfoilHat that educations don't work as loan officers as the sentence implies. It should be _For someone to work as a loan officer, an education in financial planning is required._

Comment: @user405662: Yes it is: https://studylib.net/doc/6618835/sentence-clarity

Answer (score -2):

The verb *require* needs a subject. The derived adjective is

> *required* = necessary according to the rules or for a particular purpose:
>
> We hope to be able to raise the required sum of money.
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/required?q=Required)

From this viewpoint, the sentence is correct in its use of *required*.

Nevertheless, the sentence leaves a lingering doubt. Required by what, or by whom? Is the requirement a particular one specified by the preceding context, or is it a general condition?

Because of these doubts, I would prefer, but not insist on, *necessary*, a word that does not have the feeling of an unidentified subject.